# Google script to remove duplicate rows in spreadsheet and keep the most recent entry based on timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp, google-sheets, duplicates

I have a google spreadsheet that is populated by a form, so timestamps are automatically added in the first column for each row. I have a script that removes duplicate rows in my spreadsheet (5 specific columns must be the same for it to be a duplicate, while some other columns are ignored), but I want to modify it so that if I have multiple rows for the same person's data but with different timestamps, the script will keep the most recent row. How would I do this? Thanks!

```
/** removes duplicate rows in studentsheet **/
function removeDuplicates() {
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in studentdata){
    var row = studentdata[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[1] == newData[j][1] && row[2] == newData[j][2] && row[5] == newData[j][5] && row[9] == newData[j][9] && row[10] == newData[j][10]){
      duplicate = true; //first name, last name, grade, dad's first name, and mom's first name are the same
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  StudentSheet.clearContents();
  StudentSheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  sortSheet(); //sorts sheet by 2 columns
}
```

Comment: You might be able to do it with a formula.   I just had someone help me build one that compared 2 columns and then look at the time stamp of each to tell if something should show or not.   It may take some work but I bet the formula could be adapted to only show that last unique entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751620/how-to-use-a-filter-inside-an-array-formula

Answer (score 2):

Sorts data so grouped by 'test for duplicates' data and then by date descending within group,

Starts at bottom making bottom row current row.
Current row 'test for duplicates' tested against 'test for duplicates' in row above.

If current row duplicate of one above then deletes current row leaving the row above with the later date.

If not duplicate the row above becomes the current row and tested against the one above that deleting the current row if duplicate and moving on if not.

When complete replaces existing data in spreadsheet with modified data properly sorted.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  // dataRange should not include headers
  var dataRange = s.getRange(2, 1, s.getLastRow() -1, s.getLastColumn())
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Test for duplicate columns.
  // numbers below = column number; A=1 B=2 etc.
  var lName = 2;
  var fName = 3;
  var grade = 5;
  var dad = 9;
  var mom = 10;

  for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    // add sortable date to beginning of rows
    data[i].unshift(Utilities.formatDate(data[i][0], "GMT", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
    // add sortable test for duplicates string in front of above date.
    // Placing the below in the order to be sorted by will save
    // a separate sort later
    data[i].unshift(
      data[i][lName].toLowerCase().trim() +
      data[i][fName].toLowerCase().trim() +
      data[i][grade].toString().trim() +
      data[i][dad].toLowerCase().trim() +
      data[i][mom].toLowerCase().trim()) 
  }
  // sort to group rows by test data
  data.sort();
  // reverse sort so latest date at top of each duplicate group.
  data.reverse();
  // test each row with one above and delete if duplicate.
  var len = data.length - 1;
  for( var i = len; i > 0; i-- ) {
    if(data[i][0] == data[i-1][0]) {
      data.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  // remove temp sort items from beginning of rows
  for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    data[i].splice(0, 2);
  }
  // Current sort descending. Reverse for ascending
  data.reverse();
  s.getRange(2, 1, s.getLastRow(), s.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  s.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I could get it to sort as you said, but it didn't actually delete the duplicate rows (I'm not sure why). However, I tried Krigg's solution and it worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am surprised it did not delete for you. Would it be possible, if you wouldn't mind, sharing which browser and version number you are using?

Comment: I am going to have to presume that the problem was it was on a Forms Response sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach, concattenating all columns in a single string, to save it as a object for faster searching, if you have a big sheet this can help:

```
function deleteDuplicateRowsSaveRecent(){
  var verifiedRows = {},
      curretnRow = "",
      usedRows = [1, 2, 5, 9, 10];

  for( lin in studentdata){
    curretnRow = "";
    for( ind in usedRows )
      curretnRow += studentdata[ lin ][ usedRows[ ind ] ];

    if(verifiedRows[ curretnRow ]){
      if( studentdata[ lin ][ dateColumn ] > studentdata[ verifiedRows[ curretnRow ] ][ dateColumn ] ){
        studentSheet.deleteRow(verifiedRows[ curretnRow ])
        verifiedRows[ curretnRow ] = lin;
      }else
         studentSheet.deleteRow( lin );
    }
    else
      verifiedRows[ curretnRow ] = lin;
  }
}
```

Not tested but hopefully you'll get the logic.

Comment: This worked as long as "dateColumn" was replaced by the actual column number, in my case "1". Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's why I placed dateColumn and haven't initialized it, since you didn't specified the column number I just left it there...

Comment: Actually I started doing more testing with your script and it seems to have some bugs that I can't figure out. It does not always remove all the duplicates if I run the script. If I run it multiple times it will remove more of the duplicates but it will also delete some rows that are not duplicates. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: I didn't tested it, as pasted in GAS and debugged, but the logic seems correct. You can put some values in a SS, and log them as the code run trough, to see what it is catching, some things that can be going wrong - Date format, more spaces between words. To check the first, set vars for the two Dates in the if, and log them, then compare. Also log curretnRow with lin, check which lines got deleted and search them in logger to analyze them.

Answer (score 0):

After working up my previous answer, which I believe to be the better, I considered another approach that would cause less disruption to your existing code.

You push the first non duplicate from studentdata to the new array so if studentdata is sorted by timestamp descending before the test the first non duplicate encountered that is pushed will be the latest.

Placing the following at the very beginning of you function should achieve

```
for( var i = 0; i < studentdata.length; i++ ) {
  // add sortable date to beginning of rows
  studentdata[i].unshift(Utilities.formatDate(studentdata[i][0], "GMT", "yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
  }
  studentdata.sort();
  studentdata.reverse();
  // remove temp sort date from beginning of rows
  for( var i = 0; i < studentdata.length; i++ ) {
    studentdata[i].splice(0, 1);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I decided to sort the date of submission column so that the most recent date was on top, and then run my original duplicate removal script. It seemed to work.

```
 /** sorts studentsheet by most recent submission, by last name, and then by grade/role (columns) **/
        function sortSheet() {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Students");
          sheet.sort(1, false); //sorts column A by date of submission with most recent on top
          sheet.sort(3, true); // Sorts ascending (A-Z) by column C, last name
          sheet.sort(6, true); // Sorts ascending (A-Z) by column F, grade/role
          }

    function removeDuplicates(){
          var newData = new Array();
          for(i in studentdata){
            var row = studentdata[i];
            var duplicate = false;
            for(j in newData){
              if(row[1] == newData[j][1] && row[2] == newData[j][2] && row[5] == newData[j][5] && row[9] == newData[j][9] && row[10] == newData[j][10]){
              duplicate = true; //date of submission, first name, last name, grade, dad's first name, and mom's first name are the same
              }
            }
            if(!duplicate){
              newData.push(row);
            }
          }
          StudentSheet.clearContents();
          StudentSheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData); 
 }
```